# Magento checkout silent error from PayPal address validation

Tags: magento, paypal

When a customer enters an invalid address and pays with PayPal, they are bounced back to the shopping cart with no visible error. This is caused by PayPal's address validation as described in the thread below.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/43580/disable-address-validation-for-paypal-express-checkout

Magento's exception.log file shows the error below.

> exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'PayPal NVP gateway 
>   errors: A match of the Shipping Address City, State, and Postal Code 
>   failed (#10736: Shipping Address Invalid City State Postal Code). 
>   Correlation ID: ... . Version: 72.0.' in 
>   /home/.../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php:1062

How can we either make this error visible to the customer, or disable PayPal address validation?

It would be nice if we could work around this problem using a PayPal.com account setting instead of editing Magento core files.